# How to change Bluetooth scan interval?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am building a collector application that continuously scans the Bluetooth and writes the RSSI results in a file, I used this code but it scans and records the data every 5-second.
I want to make it scan and collect the RSSI data every 100 mill second.Please help me to modify this.

```
private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            // Tried new Handler(Looper.myLopper()) also
            @Override
            public void run() {
                peripheralTextView.append("MAC: " + result.getDevice().getAddress() +","
                        + result.getDevice().getName() +","
                        +  "   RSSI: " + result.getRssi() + "\n");
            }
        });
        try {
            long TimeStampMillSec = TimeStampMillSec();
            String DateTimeToIso8601Datetimehhmmss = DateTimeToIso8601Datetimehhmmss();
            JSONObject jsonMsg =new JSONObject();
            //Edited by Mansour
            jsonMsg.put("BLue",
                    "6"+","+phoneIMEI+","+DateTimeToIso8601Datetimehhmmss+
                    ","+TimeStampMillSec+","+result.getDevice().getName()
                    + "," + result.getRssi());
            WriteMessageLog(0, jsonMsg +"\n");
            // auto scroll for text view
            final int scrollAmount =
                    peripheralTextView.getLayout().getLineTop(peripheralTextView.getLineCount())
                    - peripheralTextView.getHeight();
            // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
            if (scrollAmount > 0)
                peripheralTextView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};`
```

Comment: You show the callback that makes the scan, not how it is trigerred.

Comment: Sorry, you mean the results? @sandwood